# can't connect mysql inside docker

Tags: mysql, docker

I can't connect mysql of docker, but can connect mysql inside centos, i almost tried all method that i can find but fail to solve the problem, Meanwhile, i can't connect redis inside docker, if some docker setting is wrong?

```sh
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE       COMMAND                  CREATED        STATUS          PORTS                                                  NAMES
3a345949f38a   redis       "docker-entrypoint.s鈥?   20 hours ago   Up 5 seconds    0.0.0.0:6380->6379/tcp, :::6380->6379/tcp              redis
b4189630fe88   mysql:5.7   "docker-entrypoint.s鈥?   30 hours ago   Up 45 minutes   33060/tcp, 0.0.0.0:3307->3306/tcp, :::3307->3306/tcp   mysql
```

```
mysql> select host, user, authentication_string from mysql.user;
+-----------+---------------+-------------------------------------------+
| host      | user          | authentication_string                     |
+-----------+---------------+-------------------------------------------+
| localhost | root          | *81F5E21E35407D884A6CD4A731AEBFB6AF209E1B |
| localhost | mysql.session | *THISISNOTAVALIDPASSWORDTHATCANBEUSEDHERE |
| localhost | mysql.sys     | *THISISNOTAVALIDPASSWORDTHATCANBEUSEDHERE |
| %         | root          | *81F5E21E35407D884A6CD4A731AEBFB6AF209E1B |
+-----------+---------------+-------------------------------------------+
```

```
[root@localhost conf]# sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
```

```
[root@localhost ~]# netstat -tanlp
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3307            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3099/docker-proxy   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1247/sshd           
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2426/cupsd          
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1395/master         
tcp        0      0 172.16.33.5:22          172.16.33.29:13939      ESTABLISHED 2793/sshd: root@pts 
tcp6       0      0 :::3306                 :::*                    LISTEN      1938/mysqld         
tcp6       0      0 :::3307                 :::*                    LISTEN      3111/docker-proxy   
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1247/sshd           
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      2426/cupsd          
tcp6       0      0 ::1:25                  :::*                    LISTEN      1395/master
```

```
[root@localhost ~]# ifconfig 
docker0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255

eno16777736: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.16.33.5  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 172.16.33.255
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wAfVD.png)
the above seems no problem

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vGKpd.png)  connect message

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7XFs.png)  port=3306

Comment: i had shutdown the firewall

Comment: first check if 3306 is listening, use netstat -a

Comment: How are you starting the container? Are you using `-p` or  `-P`. How are you connecint the mysql client to the container instances?

Comment: I use SQLyog  to connect MySQL in windows,

Comment: can you please add output for `hostname -I`? I'm not sure this is the actual IP address for the machine (looks like docker IP range)

Comment: centos ip address: 172.16.33.5. I already  add output in above